# Javascript redirect in ajax success function not allowing new tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

I've been pulling my hair out for 2 hours trying to solve this would appreciate any help.

I'm trying to do a redirect into a new tab after an ajax call completes. Getting a redirect working in the success function works fine, but getting it to open in a new tab instead of the current tab is a total failure. If i run this function after a button press in javascript

```
function buildPdfPreview( picklistId, fileType, fileDestination ) {
    var previewObj = {
        encodedString: ''
    };
    var url = 'preview_document'; 
    var method = 'POST'; // method GET or POST
    var stringifyData = {'passme': encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(previewObj))};
    var target = '_blank'; // set _blank to open in a new window
    $.redirect(url, stringifyData, method, target);
}
```

a new tab gets opened no problem. $.redirect is a jquery plugin that essentially allows you to post variables in a redirect, similar to having a hidden form and then calling submit

However if i put the same redirect request inside an ajax call, it wont work, nothing happens, like so

```
function buildPdfPreview( picklistId, fileType, fileDestination ) {

   var arr = standardAjaxArray( "downloadOrEmailPicklist", 5 );
   var obj = {
       arr: arr,
       picklistId: picklistId,
       fileType: fileType,
       fileDestination: fileDestination
   };
   var stringifyData = {'passme' : encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify( obj ) ) };
   $.ajax({
        url: route() + 'global_fxns/ajaxHub',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true, 
        data: stringifyData,
        success: function(data) {       
            var previewObj = {
                encodedString: ''
            };
            var url = 'preview_document'; 
            var method = 'POST'; // method GET or POST
            var stringifyData = {'passme': encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(previewObj))};
            var target = '_blank'; // set _blank to open in a new window
            $.redirect(url, stringifyData, method, target);
        }
    });
}
```

When i run this, nothing happens, the ajax is successful but no new tab is created. The funny thing is, if i change the target from '_blank' to '', an empty string, it will redirect me in the current tab.

I've tried doing this with a hidden form and calling submit() on it instead of the $.redirect plugin and its the same thing. Could someone please help me understand why i cant create a new tab in this ajax call, but i can outside of it? And why a basic redirect within the same tab works inside or outside of the ajax call.

Thanks

Comment: could you just use: `window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');` ?   `

Comment: how would i pass post variables in that manner?